# Tangent vectors and length two subschemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

can someone explain what the datum of a point $x$ on a scheme $X$ together with a tangent direction has to do with subschemes of length two concentrated in that point?
It seems as if there would be some kind of correspondance I don't get.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See exercise II.2.8 of Hartshorne.